# osmdroid get orientation from Compass [How to]

Tags: android, dictionary, osmdroid, compass-geolocation

I use Osmdroid in my map app.

I want to get radian(oriantation) of compass for rotate map when click compass overlay.

eg. press compass icon then update orientation map true direction.

i know method setMapOrientation for rotate map
thank u.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use internal compass of the device and use SensorListener in android. Then use MapOrientation method to rotate the osmmap.

Some snippet:

```
mSensorManager.registerListener(mySensorEventListener,
                        SensorManager.SENSOR_ORIENTATION,
                        SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI);

public SensorListener mySensorEventListener = new SensorListener(){

        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(int sensor, float[] values) {
            synchronized (this) {
                float mHeading = values[0];             
                mOSMView.setMapOrientation(-mHeading);
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: SensorListener is deprecated

Comment: Doesn't matter! we can still use it.

Comment: thank u , but i dont understand .please explain for me. Thank u.

Comment: You invoke SensorListener to get realtime compass values in degrees, and then use the map.orientation method to rotate according to true norht. By default map orientation is NorthUp.

Comment: sorry, I don't understand for use this code. please help me

Comment: @zIronManBox If code is deprecated, it's for a reason!
We should find an appropriate answer without using deprecated code as it is not optimal for future devices and API that might not support this class at all anymore.